# Do equity options trade outside regular hours, similar to after hours trading for some stocks?

Tags: options, after-hours-trading

Is there an after hours trading market for equity options also, similar to that of the equity market?

I am specifically interested to know if BB (TSX) and BBRY(NASDAQ) options trade outside regular hours. And if yes, what are those hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not currently after hours trading for equity options

CBOE just in early 2015 approved after hours trading on their SPX and VIX indices (where the SPX is a derivative of a bundle of equities, and the VIX is a derivative of the SPX's options spreads... and VIX options are a derivative of the VIX, we can go deeper)

These are basically 24 hours 5.5 days of the week now with some 30 minute maintainance gaps. Not perfect to solve this glaring market inefficiency, where other markets are much more advanced in this regards, but progress.

So nothing for individual equities but you may be able to base a strategy around broad market indices

Comment: Thanks. Why is this a market inefficiency? Because models assume the ability to trade continuously? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Victor123 pricing models do not assume the ability to trade continuously. the inefficiency is that some markets trade 24/7 and affect markets that are closed. There are inefficient allocations of capital in the closed markets.